# Apache-spark installation error :unable to run spark-shell

Tags: apache-spark, spark-shell

I am facing this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKMR5.jpg) issue.
Currently mac doesn't support the cask command .
I tried installing scala 2.13.8 with jdk  17
and I am getting the exact same error message.
What is the solution for this?

I ran the following set of commands to install spark
brew install java
brew install scala
brew install apache-spark